# Cross-module static members with Google Cloud Module

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-endpoints

So I have a basic app. I've created my base app like normal with the latest Android Studio (1.4 preview now) and then added a new Google Cloud Module, with a type of App Engine with Google Cloud Messaging. Things are nice, my Endpoints seem to work as intended, messaging works etc, but I had some *best practices* questions.

In my backend module, I have a model `DeviceRecord` that is noted as an `@Entity` that has a `public static final String SOME_ID` that is specific to my Endpoint. I was hoping to easily reference this id from my *main app* by using `DeviceRecord.SOME_ID` but it throws an error. I was hoping to not have to redefine all the constants in my backend in my app as well, since they are all part of the same project.

Is this a limitation of Android Studio, or is this more of just bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to share code across your client app and backend is that right?  The backend endpoint module publishes its generated client library to be available from your app, but I believe nothing more.  If you want to share your source across both android and backend modules perhaps the best option would be to create a new 'java library' module and put your shared code in there.

The first time you try to use the shared library from your Android or Cloud module Android Studio should prompt you to import the library for you.

Comment: figured this might be the only way - thanks for the help!